# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' while running different excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I can't figure out what's causing this error. It worked totally fine with a different excel file.
Can't see where I messed up.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-d101c8c7185d> in <module>
     15 nosize_catalog_id_column = 'Catalog (No Size)'
     16 old_catalog_ids_string = 'Catalogs'   # will be the column that retains the old catalog IDs
---> 17 gbio_abs[nosize_catalog_id_column] = gbio_abs[catalog_id_column].apply(lambda x: x.replace(re.search('-\d+u', x).group(), '')).values
     18 gbio_abs[old_catalog_ids_string] = gbio_abs.groupby(nosize_catalog_id_column)[catalog_id_column].transform(lambda x: ';'.join(list(x))).values
     19 gbio_abs = gbio_abs.drop(catalog_id_column, 1)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3589             else:
   3590                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3591                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3592 
   3593         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-18-d101c8c7185d> in <lambda>(x)
     15 nosize_catalog_id_column = 'Catalog (No Size)'
     16 old_catalog_ids_string = 'Catalogs'   # will be the column that retains the old catalog IDs
---> 17 gbio_abs[nosize_catalog_id_column] = gbio_abs[catalog_id_column].apply(lambda x: x.replace(re.search('-\d+u', x).group(), '')).values
     18 gbio_abs[old_catalog_ids_string] = gbio_abs.groupby(nosize_catalog_id_column)[catalog_id_column].transform(lambda x: ';'.join(list(x))).values
     19 gbio_abs = gbio_abs.drop(catalog_id_column, 1)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: That's happening because your call `x.replace(re.search('-\d+u', x)` is returning `None`. Try changing adding an `r` _before_ the string, i.e. `r'-\d+u'` instead of `'-\d+u'`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.